# pandas sampling from series based on distribution

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy

I currently have this df (res unique values below) of strings and a distribution `p =[0.5, 0.33, 0.12, 0.05]`

```
vid    res
v1    '1072X1920'
v2    '240X416'
v3    '360X640'
v4    '720X1280'
```

The series is about 5000+ rows and I need to sample 3000 videos with the above distribution. I know I can do this by splitting the df into 4 parts, one for each res and use df.sample[:p[i] * 3000], like

```
df1072 = df[df['res'] == '1072X1920']
df1072 = df1072.sample(0.5 * 3000)
```

but is there a better way to do this? If I have 10 unique res then I would need to create 10 df in memory and that doesn't scale well. I was thinking `np.random.choice()` can help but not sure at the moment.

Comment: So you have a list of the unique values and their associated probabilities? Then really all you need should be `np.random.choice(df.res, size=3000, replace=True, p=p)`

Comment: This fails because `len(df['res']) >> len(p)`, p is only for the unique values in `df['res']`

Comment: Then how did you determine `p`? Somehow you know the relationship between the unique value in res and their probabilities. That's all you need for this and random choice. If you calculated that from your DataFrame to begin with, then all you need is `.sample`

Comment: I can't go into too much detail on p. I have 100k+ data and just need to test a few based on p. p can change at any time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example ,using `sample` random order your df, then using `np.split`

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'A':np.arange(100)})
n=len(df)
df=df.sample(n)
l=np.split(df, [int(0.5*n), int(0.83*n),int(0.95*n)])
```

Test :

```
list(map(len,l))
Out[1134]: [50, 33, 12, 5]

pd.concat(l).duplicated().any()
Out[1135]: False
```

For your example may need a `groupby` for loop

```
d={}
for y, x in df.groupby('res'): 

    n=len(x)
    x=x.sample(n)
    l=np.split(x, [int(0.5*n), int(0.83*n),int(0.95*n)])
    d.append({y:l})
```

Comment: I don't think this achieves what I want but you gave me a great idea. Your variable l is splitting x but x is already a uniq res so i just need `p` of them